# How to get jquery autocomplete to work with Express and Mongo

Tags: node.js, express, autocomplete

Not sure why the jsonp callback is not getting returned to the client.

accountcontrol.js

```
exports.find = function(req, res) { 
var b=req.query.q;   
     db.collection('catData').find({ wrapperType : "titles", titleTitles : new RegExp(b)}).limit(5).toArray(function (err, results) {
        if(results) {

        res.type('application/json');         
        res.jsonp(results);            

        } else {
           console.log("No Results")

        }
    })
}
```

app.js

```
app.get('/operations/autocompletehome', ensureLoggedIn('/login'), function(request, response) {

response.render('autocompletehome', { title: 'Autocomplete' });

});

app.get('/operations/autocomplete', accountcontrol.find)
```

autocompletehome.jade

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    meta(charset="utf-8")
    title jQuery UI Autocomplete - Remote JSONP datasource
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css")
    script(src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js")
    script(src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js")
    script(src="/javascripts/autocomplete.js")
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="/stylesheets/newstyle.css")
style
  .ui-autocomplete-loading {background: white url("images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif") right center no-repeat;}
  #city { width: 25em; }
.ui-widget
  label(for="city") Your city: 
  input#city(type="text")
  | Powered by
  a(href="http://dog.org") dog.org
    .ui-widget(style="margin-top:2em; font-family:Arial")
  | Result:
  #log.ui-widget-content(style="height: 200px; width: 300px; overflow: auto;")
```

autocomplete.js

```
 $(function() {
    function log( message ) {
      $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
      $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }

$( "#city" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/operations/autocomplete",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      data: {
        q: request.term
      },

      success: function( data ) {
        response( data );
        console.log('success', data);
      },
      complete: function() {
      console.log('done');
     }

    });
  },
  minLength: 3,
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    log( ui.item ?
      "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
      "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
  },
  open: function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
  },
  close: function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
      }
    });
  });
```

Console.Log in the Browser

```
success [
Object
_id: "546c6b509c97a9880d2b29db"
titleTitles: "06image.com"
titlesEmail: "d@c.com"
titlesName: "Fox"
titlesOwner: "Dog"
wrapperType: "titles"
__proto__: Object
```

It appears that everything is firing except for the return to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer:

Changed to json from jsonp in both the autocomplete.js and app.js

In autocomplete.js Replace:

```
success: function( data ) {
    response( data );
    console.log('success', data);
  },
```

With:

```
success: function( data ) {
        response($.map(data, function(item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.titleTitles

                    };
                }));
      },
```

Enables JQuery to parse the Mongo array.
Hope this helps others who are woking with Jade, Mongo  and Express trying to learn how to implement Ajax.